# Home page to communicate two different services of equal importance

Tags: website-design, user-centered-design, copywriting

I understand that this could be a duplicate question, but I feel that none so far have answered mine.

My client has two services, and he wants one website essentially split into two sections which are fine because each one can be marketed separately to the correct audience and sites can always be easily divided, etc.

However, each service has its specific message, and the thing I'm struggling to understand is how the homepage (above the fold) can communicate two different ideas without confusing the user especially when viewed on a mobile phone.

Should I combine any shared qualities between the two and somehow create a single value proposition statement (maybe around the experience the companies offers on the whole) and place two buttons for each service directly underneath it?

To take this a little further we can introduce social media into this problem. You wouldn't create two of every social media account for each service; you would probably try to build a unified brand/message however you could.

So does that mean your homepage should take on the same approach?

I hope this isn't seen as a duplicate question and thanks to anyone who wishes to help me solve it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest path to this seems to be something like a split screen landing page, where a visitor can choose their desired path right off the bat. But my thought for your situation is that if you can't find data supporting one method over the other, maybe your question should be answered by an A/B test: try two versions of the landing page, one with a single statement and CTA and one with split up statements/CTAs, and look at how each one affects visitor behavior.

Messaging will also be important, a good design with confusing copywriting still won't convert well!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tobybot, it's a big help. I was hoping to avoid split screen, but if in doubt you should always test. I've not done any A/B tests before but its something I would like to do. Can you recommend any A/B testing platforms I can explore, hopefully at a free level and more than a free trial? I believe (don't quote me) there are some PHP code snippets around online I can use in conjunction with Google analytics. For a free A/B test, is this something you would recommend for a newbie who doesn't want to commit to things like Crazy Egg subscriptions just yet?

Comment: Maybe check out the free level of Google Optimize: https://www.google.com/analytics/optimize/

Answer (score 0):

By no means should you try to reach both audiences with one message. By trying to reach both, you reach none. I agree with tobybot's general recommendation. The one note is that if you do it horizontally (even if both featured are above the fold), it may seem like a top-down hierarchy, with the top getting possibly getting more views/ apparent preference. Similarly, if the website's in English/western language, with the vertical, side-by-side approach (my preference), people will see the one on the left first, unless the visuals and copy somehow pull the person in to the appropriate one.

As a copywriter, I'll also underscore the huge role your strong and clear messaging (and likewise strong and clear copy) will have in the design. Make sure you have your messaging down (know your mission, vision, differentiators especially), which all starts with clearly defining the audiences. Personas will help with this.

Another random thought is that if there are really two main customers, you could qualify the customer through the design, a sort of creative approach to a TurboTax-style wizard. Through a short serious of qualifying questions (implemented creatively), you bring them to a landing page for each respective service. For people who might fall into an "Other" category, you could lead them to your About page, contact page, or some other informational landing page about your company/services.

Re: social media needed two different accounts. Um, it depends. It depends on the size of the company, how much time and energy you have to do separate accounts, have two sets of goals, etc. If it's a good sized company, go for it. If not so much, it might not be worth it. You can always plug two services distinctly under one umbrella brand profile.